# Laravel page not loading external Files (CSS & JS)

Tags: laravel, include

I setup the following Routes for now (Moving a barebone php project to laravel):

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});

Route::get('cat/a', function (){
    return view('cat.cat_a');
});
```

Both Files include 4 other Files located in /resources/views/includes. I load those files using:

```
@include('includes.header')
@include('includes.sidebar_a')

[...] Content [...]

@include('includes.sidebar_b')
@include('includes.footer')
```

All includes are correctly included in both, domain.com/ aswell as domain.com/cat/a but whitin the view domain.com/cat/a all included css & js files (included in footer.blade.php & header.blade.php) return 404.

Here is my file structure:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [asset](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-asset) helper to generate links to JS&CSS:

```
{{ asset('js/main.js') }}
```

In this case you'll get HTML with correct paths.

Comment: Works nice, thank you. However just without the smemicolon